# Grails war size is more than 60 MB by default

Tags: grails, war

I'am working on a Grails 2.4.5 project and observed that my war file size is whopping 80 MB.

So, I tried a sample Grails 2.4.5 project without any additional dependencies and created WAR. It's almost 60 MB.

May I know what's the reason behind this? Without any additional Jars why is the WAR size is that big?

I went through the lib folder in WAR file and saw that compile time dependencies like grails plugins are present there.As per my knowledge, only runtime dependencies should appear in WAR. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Hi the reason could be the following:

1. grails is a mix of many frameworks, spring, hibernate etc. All the frameworks are included and you need them as they are the baseline of grails
2. every grails application comes with many plugins by default (look into your BuildConfig.groovy): cache, asset, scaffolding... just to name a few. Every plugin has their own dependencies like classes, jars, js... All of them add up

Sollution:
a war and also a jar are just containers. Open them with your favorite unzip program and check

Anyway I don't see the point in having a "large" war file. But maybe my answers helps you in understanding the reason why.